# How can I share an event handler?

Tags: windows, forms, sharing, eventhandler

private void ExitAndSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            foreach (Form form in MdiChildren)
            {
                if (form is TextForm tf)
                {
                    tf.BringToFront();
                    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your document?", "Save document?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

```
                if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    //counter++;
                    var textBoxValue = tf.FetchTextBoxValue();
                    //string filePath = $"{DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()}.txt";
                    string filePath = $"composition{DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()}.txt";
                    File.WriteAllText(filePath, textBoxValue);
                }
                if (dr == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    continue;
                }

            }
            else if (form is ImageDocumentForm)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please note that only text documents can be saved.", "Advisory:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }

        }
        Close();
    }
```

This code works fine. I need it to be called when the user exits the program. I'm not able to assign this event to the form closing event in the design view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event argument needs to be of the form **FormClosingEventArgs e**
Change that and try again.

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorry for the messy post.